# How can you make you app close, but get Safari to play a radio stream

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've seen a radio app, from a local radio station that has the option to play the stream in the background. So you press the button in the app, the app closes and then Safari opens and plays the stream through Quicktime.

How is this done? I think it is a really nice feature. Was under the impression that your app cant interact with the phone in this way. Like its 'sandboxed'.

Thanks
-Code

Comment: The only (?) way to interact with other applications is by using URLs. You can use the method shown by Radek to open another application that is able to load a particular URL scheme (ie, http:, mailto:, twitter:). You can also have apps load files from other apps (like iBooks loads PDFs from Safari), but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: @Matthew Schinckel this can be done with encoding the contents of the file in Base64. There must be a better way, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *pth = @"http://www.example.com/stream.mp3";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pth]];
```

Although this is not needed anymore as iOS 4 supports multitasking for all apps. Previous iOSes only supported multitasking for Safari, iPod and Mail (and Phone? dunno).

Comment: What do you mean by 'this is not needed anymore'. What is the alternative you seem to hint at? You mean that you can minimize your app and play the radio through the app while it is minimized, and not need to kill ur app and play it via safari?  Can people then use other apps while you app is playing the radio?

Comment: You can play audio and stream data from your app while it is minimized. Even the back, play and forward buttons can be used from the multitasking menu. Safari isn't needed anymore.

Comment: And those of us still on iPhone 3G cannot use multitasking. So the 'load a stream in Safari' still is very useful.

Comment: @Matthew a good solution would be using multitasking if it is supported, Safari otherwise. It is easy to detect this at runtime. Multitasking is just better for the user and it doesn't prevent them from browsing the web.